# How can I log in into iCloud.com from an iPhone?

Tags: icloud, ios

I lost my iPhone and i had a lot of important contacts and documents in my iCloud mail account. The only "computer" I currently have available is my friend's iPhone which is connected to his own iCloud account. Is there a way to log into icloud.com from an iPhone?

Comment: You need the iCloud account but you can log in on the web or with a Mac. Yor question is not clear do you mean account or using a iphone

Comment: Ok look, I'm on my friends iPhone, my iPhone was stolen and I'm trying to log into my icloud account from his phone.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Google Chrome for iOS to go to https://www.icloud.com/ and force it to show you the desktop version, by clicking on the "Request Desktop Site" menu option. Then you get the login form, and you can login as usual.

[image]
[Image source](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2012/06/29/top-10-google-chrome-features-for-ios/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly answering your question, but if you're looking to change your iCloud password then… 
If you remember your Apple ID and password, you can login from another non-iPhone device using a current web browser. The address is https://www.icloud.com.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately Webkit on the iHone detects you are on an iPhone and does not gove the iCloud.com login page. So you can't login with Safari or Chrome

Comment: You're correct. My answer doesn't answer the OP question about accessing from an iPhone with another existing iCloud account.

Answer (score 1):

Use Puffin. There is a free version in the app store (you don't need the paid version for this). https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/puffin-web-browser-free/id472937654?mt=8

I use Puffin to (successfully) get around the limitations of Safari/mobile/touch browsers in a lot of difficult situations.

I have just tried, and you can successfully log in to iCloud.com on iOS with Puffin and access Mail. A hint: You may need to pinch-to-zoom out sometimes to get the interface to redraw to fit your screen, even though it's not obvious this will work. Just try it if things aren't displaying right ;)

I don't use iCloud mail, so I couldn't actually try to load a message or read it, but at least I know you can log in.